# JSONPath first occurrence of "gatherer"

Tags: jsonpath

I have a json file like this:

```
{
  "cards": [
    {
      "artist": "Steve Argyle",
      "images": {
        "mtgimage": "http://mtgimage.com/set/pMPR/ponder.jpg"
      },
    },
    {
      "artist": "Mark Tedin",
      "images": {
        "gatherer": "http://gatherer.wizards.com/Handlers/Image.ashx?type=card&multiverseid=139512",
        "mtgimage": "http://mtgimage.com/set/LRW/ponder.jpg"
      },
    },
    {
      "artist": "Dan Scott",
      "images": {
        "gatherer": "http://gatherer.wizards.com/Handlers/Image.ashx?type=card&multiverseid=190159",
        "mtgimage": "http://mtgimage.com/set/M10/ponder.jpg"
      },
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to get the first "gatherer" link from it using JSONPath.
I tried "$..gatherer[0]" but that doesn't work. However "$..gatherer" does give both instances:

```
[
   "http:\/\/gatherer.wizards.com\/Handlers\/Image.ashx?type=card&multiverseid=139512",
   "http:\/\/gatherer.wizards.com\/Handlers\/Image.ashx?type=card&multiverseid=190159"
]
```

How do I get only the first one? (without getting the last one in code, so only using a jsonpath string.)

(Tested with http://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/ and in my program.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need an interim step to save the array

```
var gatherers = $..gatherer;  //however this gets it, I'm not sure
var first = gatherers[0];
```

that may work.

Comment: That should indeed work. However I'm looking for a jsonpath-only solution. The idea is that users can input their own jsonpath strings. Getting the first "gatherer" link is something I expect will need to be used. So I'm hoping for a solution that doesn't require code, and can be done with only a jsonpath string.